# Rake creating a rule that uses multitask

Tags: ruby, parallel-processing, rake

If I create a simple rule like

```
rule '.o' => ['.c'] do |t|
  sh "cc #{t.source} -c -o #{t.name}"
end
```

How can I tell Rake that I want the auto-generated tasks to be parallelizable?

Comment: and by parallelizable you mean exactly what?

Comment: by using Thread.new and 'join' http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_multithreading.htm - As I get it he wants to execute the same code for each file in the dir in parallel.

Comment: I was wondering if there was a builtin primitive to do this, like MultiTask mentioned below but for "rule" tasks

Answer (score 5):

as stated by Dennis Rake rules are implemented as Tasks

therefore the -m flag which converts tasks to multitasks also converts rules to 'multirules'

```
require 'rake/clean'

rule '.ext2' => '.ext1' do |t|
    sh "cp #{t.source} #{t.name}"
    sleep(1)
end

def dependencies(input_file)
    base, is, ext = input_file.split('.')
    _from, _to = is.split('-')
    files = []
    Integer(_from).upto(Integer(_to)) do |i|
        files << "#{base}_#{i}.#{ext}"
    end
    return files
end

rule ".ext2" => lambda { |i| dependencies(i) } do |t|
    sh "touch #{t.source}"
end

task :make_files do |t|
    1.upto(20) do |i| 
        sh "touch file_#{i}.ext1"
    end
end

CLEAN = FileList['*.ext2']
```

running the following commands (not threaded):

```
rake make_files
time rake file.1-20.ext2
```

I get

```
real    0m20.232s
user    0m0.134s
sys     0m0.082s
```

with 5 threads:

```
rake clean
time rake -m -j 5 file.1-20.ext2
```

I get

```
real    0m4.152s
user    0m0.122s
sys     0m0.071s
```

with 20 threads:

```
rake clean
time rake -m -j 20 file.1-20.ext2
```

I get

```
real    0m1.167s
user    0m0.130s
sys     0m0.065s
```

I use sleep(1) to emulate 'work/io', if your processes block a lot or if you have many cores this might be useful to you :)

**EDIT:** As pointed out by Shadow in comments, the follow toggles 'multitask' to be always on

```
Rake.application.options.always_multitask = true
```

Comment: Very nice - but is there a way to allow this behavior by default?

Comment: I found a way to do it that is a little hacks - but if you have `Rake.application.options.always_multitask = true` in your rake file, it will enable this option. It's dodgy though because it doesn't allow the command line to override it that way, but that doesn't worry me in this application.

Answer (score 1):

The question, isn't very clear, but isn't Rake::MultiTask what you're looking for?

http://rake.rubyforge.org/Rake/MultiTask.html

I've neverused it myself, but the docs suggest:

```
multitask :copy_files => [:copy_src, :copy_doc, :copy_bin] do
  puts "All Copies Complete"
end
```

http://rake.rubyforge.org/files/doc/rakefile_rdoc.html

The definition of `rule` in the DSL is in `lib/rake/dsl_definitions.rb` (in Rake 10.1.1):

```
# Declare a rule for auto-tasks.
#
# Example:
#  rule '.o' => '.c' do |t|
#    sh %{cc -o #{t.name} #{t.source}}
#  end
#
def rule(*args, &block)
  Rake::Task.create_rule(*args, &block)
end
```

A cursory scan of the current code yields nothing built-in for the `rule` construct in the DSL, though. In case it helps, searching the code for things like `@rules` and `rules.` yields a single interesting call in `lib/rake/task_manager.rb` in the form of `enhance_with_matching_rule()`.

Comment: So essentially, what I want is like multitaks, but with "rule" tasks. i.e. if you do: rule '.o' => ['.c'] do |t| I want all .c files to compile in parallel not sequentially

Comment: @alexspeller: I haven't dived into Rake's code in a while, but if I remember correctly, a rule is syntactic sugar for a task that performs a regular set of instructions. If you scan the DSL's source code for `def rule` you'll probably end up finding the needed Task syntax. If so, copying that and replacing Task with Multitask should then do the trick.

Comment: @alexspeller: so… I dove in to take a deeper look and, in fact, `rule`  seems to merely *extend* a Task using `enhance_with_matching_rule()`. I've updated my answer somewhat to highlight this, and I suspect it might be possible to create or override the built-in compile task to make it run across multiple threads. (I'm guessing Rake's maintainer will be happy to incorporate this if it works and you pull it off.)

Comment: Thanks for taking a look, I will investigate this further from that starting point

Comment: @alexspeller -m converts tasks to multitasks, because rules are tasks this also works for rules, see my answer for an example :)

Answer (score 1):

I've struggled with this for a bit. The problem is that `rule` doesn't allow for parallel execution of its dependencies, while `multitask` allows for neither regex- or glob-based matching, nor for lambdas as dependencies. The latter just gives you `Don't know how to build task '#<Proc:0x007fd95a4ce3f8@/Rakefile:14 (lambda)>' (see --tasks)`.

The pattern I have adopted is to assemble a MultiTask dynamically. The following will match something like "stuff_to_do:12:455:3434" and execute tasks "task_12", "task_455", and "task_3434" in parallel:

```
rule /stuff_to_do:(:?[0-9]+)+/ => :environment do |t|
     doer = Rake::MultiTask.new("stuff",Rake.application)
     doer.enhance(t.name.split(':')[1..-1].map{|number| "task_#{number}"})
     doer.invoke
  end
```

end